# Deleting cell from a Table - With Code - Logic Issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a `BarButton` Item and the name of it is `Edit` when it is in edit mode, and `Done` when it is done with editing. So when the user clicks on edit the `editpress` method gets executed (see code).

With that the, `commitEditingStyle` , and the cell and the record (from the array which is used to add data to the cell) is deleted.

The problem : When i click on delete, the cell gets deleted from the table correctly. But not from the array which is used to load the cells. When i placed a debug point at `commitEditingStyle`, it only executes that code when i FIRST click on delete. If i delete records for the 2nd, 3rd etc this code block is not executed. Why is this ?

I have not added `[self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];` record in `commitEditingStyle`. Is that the flaw.

note: i don't think my delete from array logic is incorrect, because the same logic works in other programs (gurantted, and that's why i didnt post it)

```
  -(void) editpress:(id)sender{
        UIBarButtonItem *editButton = (UIBarButtonItem*)self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem;    
        if (!self.tableView.editing) {  
            [self.tableView setEditing:YES animated:YES];
            UIButton *rbut= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [rbut setImage:rightImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];       
            [rbut addTarget:self action:@selector(editpress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
            UIBarButtonItem *rBarButDone =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rbut];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rBarButDone;       
        }
        else { 
            [self.tableView setEditing:NO animated:YES];
            UIButton *rbut= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
            [rbut setImage:rightImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];              
            [rbut addTarget:self action:@selector(editpress:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];        
            UIBarButtonItem *rBarButEdit =  [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rbut];
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rBarButEdit;
        }
    }


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {        
        [self.tableView beginUpdates];
        // I write the logic to delete the record from the array and the table here.         
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]  withRowAnimation:YES];  
        [self.tableView endUpdates];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Comment: You said the object is not deleted from the data source array. Did you use [self.tableView reloadData]?

Comment: Yes, i did and also i mentioned that the `commitEditingStyle` is only executed the first time

Comment: You need to post the code that removes the object from the array.  That is where your problem is.

Comment: So you think that the code not executing the `commitEditingStyle ` when the user deletes an record is normal ?

Comment: Well, actually i am sending the selected item to a web service to delete. So i don't think i have to copy the code here (It's written in JAVA). After deleting a record i call another webservice to populate the table with the new records (after deleting)

Comment: Like Owen said, you don't have any code that deletes the object from the array. The `commitEditingStyle:` message you showed only deletes rows from the table view -- this doesn't magically change your underlying data structure. As for why it's not called the second time, I don't see enough info here to figure that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is obviously executing the commitEditingStyle.  However, after you delete, does the cellForRowAtIndexPath now return the correct data for the row that was deleted?  If you're reading that data from an internal array that you downloaded, then you need to delete an item from that internal array.  If you're reading from another source, you need to either make sure that source is sending the correct data, or you're refreshing it after deleting the row.  In either case, whatever your "web service" is doing to delete the data is not refreshing the cell with new data.  Also, you'll need to report one fewer in numberOfRowsInSection: method.